# How does Executable able to run on different CPUs for Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, executable

I heard that Assembly Languages are depending on the CPU, and the fact that a .exe file can mostly all Windows machine. Makes me wonder how does that work?

Does that imply that there are only a few Assembly languages?

or
Does the Windows System do some sort of translation to fit different type of CPUs?

Comment: Because those different CPUs all use the same instruction set, that is x86 or x86-64. It won't run if you use a different one, like ARM. Windows wont even install in that.

Comment: try running a 64-bit binary on 32-bit Windows and see

Comment: @Havenard You'd better declare that you have excluded Embedded, IoT and RT 8/8.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The simple answer:**

They cannot be executed on "different CPUs".

**The more complex answer:**

Most computers running Windows use only **two** different types of CPUs: x86 or x86-64.

- x86-64 is compatible with x86 so you can run an executable compiled for x86 on an x86-64 CPU.
- You **cannot** run an executable compiled for x86-64 on an x86 CPU.
- There are Windows computers using different CPUs (ARM, MIPS, SuperH...). You **cannot** run an executable compiled for these CPUs on x86-64 nor on x86 CPUs. On the other hand you **can only** run executables compiled for the specific CPU type (ARM, MIPS, SuperH...) on such a computer.

Then there are so called **".NET" executables**. Such executables do **not** contain any machine code but they contain special byte code (similar to Java programs).

When you run the program the first time on a certain computer Windows will translate that byte code into machine code suitable for the computer you run the program on. If you run the program on an ARM computer the byte code will be translated into an ARM program.

The computer will actually execute the "translation", not the original ".NET" executable.

Because the "translation" is done for a specific computer there is no need to be executable on different CPUs.

Comment: ARM64 support is coming to Windows 10 desktop -- probably with 32-bit x86 emulation to run existing WinAPI applications.

Comment: @eryksun why don't they rather simply recompile all packages from source, like in other OSes? Bothering with emulation... crazy.

Comment: @Ped7g, practically speaking, that won't happen. Applications depend on closed-source libraries and other applications that are outside of their control. In some cases maybe no one even has the source code anymore. Even if they have all of the code, it may be so poorly written and untested that porting it to a new architecture isn't worth it in terms of time and cost. Emulating x86 is a must-have feature if the Windows desktop is to support ARM64 and bootstrap market support.

Comment: @Ped7g how would they compile Adobe sources? did you see their demo? It's a win32 Photoshop running on Windows on ARM. Obviously all Windows apps would be compiled into ARM

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc If you talk about the MS demonstration: This demonstration demonstrates an x86 CPU emulator running on ARM. So the applications are actually running on an emulated x86 CPU.

Comment: @MartinRosenau so what do you mean? Obviously Photoshop must run in an x86 emulator? Ped7g asked why MS don't recompile the binaries and there's no way for MS to get the source code and recompile to run it in ARM.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Ah. Sorry. But the answer seems to be simple to me: "Simply re-compiling" is only half of the work: Adobe had to provide software updates for both x86 and ARM. They had to do tests for all software they release etc. This is too much work for only some few customers who run Windows on ARM.

Comment: I think Ped7g's comment snuck past the sarcasm detectors of everyone who replied.  That's what GNU/Linux distros can do because they use portable Free software.  The Windows world is a lot less convenient and portable, where it's apparently not rare for people to only have a 32-bit binary DLL copy of some important library their software is built around.